# MEF error in form designer?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

I am using MEF and my plugin directory is `c:\dev\plugins`

I have a form, but when I open it up, I have the following error:

> The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information. 1) The export 'Helper (ContractName="IHelper")' is not assignable to type 'IHelper'. Resulting in: Cannot set import 'helper (ContractName="IHelper")' on part 'Manager'. Element: helper (ContractName="IHelper") --> Manager`

I have two assemblies that contain the same exports, but I am using `DirectoryCatalog` to only load one of them at a time.

This error only seems to show in the designer.  When I run the code, I don't get an exception and the app runs fine.  The designer does give me the option to `Ignore and Continue` but I did this once and it failed, so I am holding back.

```
public class Manager
    {

        private static readonly Manager instance = new Manager();

        public static IHelper Helper { get { return Manager.instance.helper; } }

        [Import(typeof(IHelper))]
        internal IHelper helper { get; set; }

        private Manager()
        {

           using (DirectoryCatalog catalog = 
                                    new DirectoryCatalog(@"c:\dev\plugins"))
           {
               using (CompositionContainer container = 
                                              new CompositionContainer(catalog))
               {
                      container.ComposeParts(this);
               }
            }
        }
     }

public interface IHelper
    {
        string LabelText { get; }
    }


[Export(typeof(IHelper))]
public class SpecificHelper : IHelper
{
    public string LabelText
    {
         get { return "Id:"};
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are debugging, before you compose, set a breakpoint and see how many parts were discovered in the catalogs. I would also ensure that the correct part was composed (that your directory catalog is point at the right place).

Comment: It finds 1 part.  The directory (FullPath) is correct.  It finds 1 ExportDefinition and 0 ImportDefinitions.

Comment: Can you post your composition code?

Comment: @Jim - I posted code.  I don't know if this matters, but one of the things I am doing with MEF besides custom logic is Custom UI work as well, for example, changing labels at runtime depending on which assembly it finds.

Comment: I realized if I remove all the MEF code, the designer shows up fine,  If I add a try catch, the designer shows up fine too.

Comment: Can you also post your IHelper implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the implementation of the interface, not the interface itself. I believe it would be your "Helper" class.

Comment: @Jim - Ah OK, I posted one implementation.

Comment: I believe the problem is in your form's code. Can you post its constructor and anything it imports, if at all?

Comment: @AdiLester - The only thing I am doing in the form's (constructor) code is `txtId.Text = Manager.Helper.LabelText;`

Comment: I use the same code and get no exception.

Comment: @AdiLester - I don't get an exception at run-time. Everything works fine. I only get an exception when I am viewing the form in the designer.  If I put a try/catch or remove the mef code, the designer exception goes away.